# Call controller from view and pass value from view to controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

In view page, I have an html.actionlink:
1. How to call from html.actionlink, an actionresult name, that is inside the homecontroller(How to write the address of the controller and function, in actionlink?)
2. How to pass a number of variables from view\html.actionlink to homecontroller\actionresult?
Thanks

Comment: You can pass the varibales like id as part of the routeValues parameter of the RedirectToAction() method.

`return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { id = 12 });`

This will cause a redirect to Site/Controller/Action/12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Html.ActionLink(article.Title, "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = article.ArticleID, title = article.Title }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you for passing some variables from View to controller/action to use this simple way :

submit button

So now whene you clicked in the button the form will be submit and will be pass the text value that have IH="test_var" to the action .
Now in the controller we use this method to get the variable :

Imagin we have a controller that named controller inside this controller we use

Public actionresult simple_action (string test_var)
{

//here you can write what you want to code

}

I wish this help you brother .